# Typescript error in map(): Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have an array (iotDatas) of:

```
interface iotData {
 id: string;
 device_id: string;
 color: number;
 ph: number
 created_at: string;
}
```

a state to select between the 'color' and 'ph' properties, with a default value 'color':

```
const [selecetedPropriety, setSelectedPropriety] = useState('color');
```

and this map return a typescrip error:

```
const yesterdayData = iotDatas.map(iotDada => {
 return { x: iotDada.created_at, y: iotDada[selecetedPropriety]};
});

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ioTData'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'ioTData'
```

i dont know what to do.

Thans for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the first thing here is that `iotData` is not an array, it is an object, which you are trying to access using a key of this object. I believe you can use `as keyof` here. Such as below, which specifies that the string is a key of `iotData`

```
iotData[selecetedPropriety as keyof iotData]
```